# Photos Gallery In iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

I want to make photos gallery like one in this photo:

[image]

Is there any help how to make it the easiest way

Comment: May I know why are the delete and negative voting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a openflow api written by Alex Fajkowski. Here is link to it: http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/

Comment: I found a detailed way how to make it in this URL:http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/